# Extra space on my page when viewed on a smartphone

Tags: css, viewport

I want [my page](http://goo.gl/4Vmkx0) to be non-responsive. It's about 1000px wide. I want it to appear in totality on my smartphone, so that the user has to zoom in to read normal sized characters.

Yet no matter what I do, I always have hundreds of pixels on the right of the main content when viewed on smartphone. I tried to set `width: 1050px` to a "wrap" element containing my whole page, same result. Right now my body tag is set to `width: 1050px`, same result.

I tried without viewport tag. Then I tried with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1050, initial-scale=1">`.

Ideally on a smartphone I would want the page to appear horizontally centered with some 30px padding on each side, with no possibility to scroll horizontally. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and change the meta tag to

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`